# Linear Alg. Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am brand new to learning about subspaces in my linear Algebra class. Ive tried to follow khan academy but to no avail. I encountered these practice problems in the textbook. However my textbook inconveniently provides answers for odd numbered problems only.

I want to further my understanding. Could someone please explain how to go about these problems?

### Given vector space V = the set of all 2 × 2 matrices.....

```
*1) Show that the sum of two 2 × 2 nonsingular matrices may be
   singular.

 2) Show that the sum of two 2 × 2 singular matrices may be nonsingular.*
```

Thank you

Comment: What did you try for these problems? Did you try to come up with an example for either?

Comment: Ive been sitting at the problems for about an hour now. I cant seem to make sense of them given the info in my text book :(

Comment: @RebeccaElwood did you write things down?

Comment: Well, you didn't really answer my question, so let me ask this: do you understand what the question is telling you to do? Do you know what a "singular matrix" is?

Comment: A square matrix that has the property of the determinant being 0?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Instead of summing two random non-singular matrices hoping to get a singular matrix, try from the other direction: Take an obviously singular matrix. For example both the rows are identical, say $\displaystyle A={2\quad 3\choose 2\quad3}$. Change a single entry, call the resulting matrix  $A_1$ and define $A_2= (A-A_1)$  . Now your experimentation is focussed: what changes will make both $A_1$ and $A_2$ non-singular.

Do the same for part 2.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to come up with an example for each case.

1) You want to find some $A$ and $B$ nonsingular (i.e. invertible/determinant nonzero) whose sum is not invertible. I would go with I and -I, but maybe try and find your own.

2) Similarly, you just need to find an example
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
do nicely.